# Ubuntu 14.04: I have 2 monitors, and full screen spans both of them. I only want full screen on one monitor

Tags: 14.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I see lot's of people wanting to have full screen span both monitors, yet I only want to be able to full screen an application on ONE of the monitors.

Here is my /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:8:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I actually have 2 different graphics cards (for 3 monitors in windows), but am only wanting to access 2 of my monitors when I am on Ubuntu.

Full screen currently looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxQUl.png]

Comment: Why do you have an xorg.conf?

Comment: Uhm not entirely sure to be honest. I found a guide online that said I should have one of those to determine the monitor priority. I've done lots of research online but can't quite wrap my head around the whole ubuntu monitor/gfx card setup.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using the noveau driver. I would suggest moving the xorg.conf out of the way, rebooting, and then configuring your desired display using the Display settings panel in System Settings.

Once you've got your configuration working as desired, you can copy the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file to `/etc/gnome-settings-daemon/xrandr/monitors.xml` to have the configuration applied on boot for lightdm as well.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try when I get home and update you with what happens!